# How to count number of element in an int type array where 0 can be an element?

Tags: c, arrays, count

**Expectation**:  I want to count number of element available in an `int` type of array where `0` can be an element.

Following program output:

```
Total Element :6
```

Expected output:

```
Total Element :9
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a[50] = { 1, 2, -3, 0, 0, 6, 7, -8, 0 };
    int count = 0;

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (a[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("Total Element :%d ", count);

    return 0;
}
```

NB: I want to count the total number of elements in the array. I do not want to count the size of the array.

Comment: Just change the `if(a[i]){count++;}` part with `count++;`

Comment: in this case output will be 50 @keine

Comment: Why not use `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)`

Comment: Do you want to count the number of initialization lists?
So like [this](https://ideone.com/8XY96g)

Comment: @H. M. MOHIDUL ISLAM SHOVON You can not to calculate the number of explicitly initialized elements such a way. The code does not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to count Total number of element in array

As it stands, you cannot.

In C an array does *not* know which elements ever had been used or not.

If it is not possible to define a sentinel, a stopper-value, but you know the initialiser you *could* do the following:

```
#include <stddef.h> /* for size_t */
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_INITIALISER {1, 2, -3, 0, 0, 6, 7, -8, 0}


int main()
{
    int a[50] = ARRAY_INITIALISER;
    size_t count;

    {
      int tmp[] = ARRAY_INITIALISER;

      count = sizeof tmp / sizeof *tmp;
    }

    printf("Total number of elements 'used': %zu\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a fixed buffer of 50 elements, but the "active" array can have any length and you have no valid sentinel element (such as the null character in strings, or may eb a `NULL` pointer or 0 or −1 or `INT_MIN` in integer arrays), *you must keep track of the active length* `count` from the start:

```
int a[50] = {1, 2, -3, 0, 0, 6, 7, -8, 0};
int count = 9;
```

If you want to build the array dynamically, start with an ampty array and a zero count, then "push" the elements to the array:

```
int a[50];
int count = 0;

a[count++] = 1;
a[count++] = 2;
a[count++] = -3;
a[count++] = 0;
```

Take care not to overflow the underlying fixed-size array.

Comment: this is not the solution what  exactly I want

Comment: Then hve a look at alk's answer and Bluepixy's ideone link. Those answers will only give you the initial count of active elements, though, so when you want to change the array, you wil have to use a technique similar to the one I've shown you. (And if you don't want to change the array, there's no point to reserve 50 elements; just use `int a[] = {...}` and then use `sizeof`.)

Comment: 1+ and I took the freedom to emphasize the most essential and import part of your answer ...

Comment: Is it because the elements of 0 are being identified as equivalent to \0?

Comment: @ShaunF: Why are you referring to \0?

Comment: When I was testing the ways I could check for the end of an array (even for integers) I found that 0, '\0' and NULL all worked the same @alk

Comment: That's because all these have the value 0. It is okay to use `0` everywhere, but it is idiomatic to use `'\0'` for the terminating null character and `NULL` for the null pointer. Interchanging them arbitrarily is confusing and might even produce warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sentinel value, i.e. choose a magic number (like 0xDEADBEEF).

and change your code like this:

```
#define SENTINEL 0xDEADBEEF

int main() {
    int a[50] = { 1, 2, -3, 0, 0, 6, 7, -8, 0, SENTINEL };
    int count = 0;

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (a[i] == SENTINEL)
            break;
        if (a[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Total Element :%d ", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: For the sake of portability (always try to) use any of the well defined values as sentinel, as there are in this case : `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX` or `0`.